# Did I install this motion detecting light switch correctly?

Tags: electrical, lighting

It works, I just want to make sure I did it correctly. It's a [Leviton ODS10-ID](https://www.leviton.com/fr/docs/Data_Sheet-Passive_Infrared_Wall_Switch_%28ODS10-ID%29.pdf) Decora 120/277-Volt Wall Switch with Occupancy Sensor

When I took the original switch off the wall it had no ground connected and a red and black wire going to it.

I installed the green ground wire from the switch into the existing 3 bare copper wires that were in a yellow wire nut which I upgraded to a red since I was now adding a 4th wire. One bare wire connected to the metal box and the other two go into the wall.

I attached the black hot from the new switch into the black wire in the wall that was connected to the old switch. I attached the blue wire from the new switch to the red wire that was attached to the old switch.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you have a metal box which is grounded, a switch can self-ground via the mounting screws, provided the yoke (the screws go through) and the screws are metal.  So in this case there is no requirement to use the ground wire also.   This method does not work on receptacles unless they make hard-flush contact with the metal box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks good. If you were concerned about the "red" .vs. "black" on your load wiring, don't be. Generic instructions often don't do well in specific cases.